# Where can I download a copy of Mainnet Blocks?

Tags: nodeos, block-producer

I want to download the blockchain to speed up the syncing process, I know some BPs were providing this service but I can´t find the url.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From a paid standby block producer:
<strike>https://eosnode.tools/blocks</strike>

The eosnode.tools is now discontinued.

Try https://snapshots.eosnation.io/.

Answer (score 1):

Now(2020.08.08) you can get blocks.log from here https://archive.eoseoul.io/